# Trying to take a date as input in python and updating value in mysql table using mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, str-to-date

My aim here is to update an existing table in mysql database taking all the variables for the update statement as input from the user. I am using mysqlconnector to interface with python.

```
    coltbu=input("Now enter the name of the column whose value for that row/condition is to be updated")
    if coltbu=="dob":
        y1=input("Enter the value to be set for date of joining in yyyy-mm-dd")    
    elif col=="id":
        nval=int(input("Enter the value to be set for salary"))  
    else:
        nval=input("Enter the value to be set for this column")
    x='%d-%m-%Y'
    tup=(coltbu,y1,x,col,val)
    print(tup)
    cursor1.execute("Update student set %s=str_to_date(%s,%s) where %s=%s"%tup)
    con1.commit()
    con1.close()
```

I have lots of variations after searching for solutions painstakingly on the internet, but I can't seem to find anything that works. Some error or the other always shows up
In this case the table I am using is 
[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fghtm.png)

The command I am trying to execute is 
`update student set dob='2003-09-12' where id=6;`

I also tried to use datetime for this to work.

```
    coltbu=input("Now enter the name of the column whose value for that row/condition is to be updated")
    if coltbu=="dob":
        y=int(input("Enter the value to be set for dob in yyyy/mm/dd. First enter year and hit enter"))
        m=int(input("Now enter month"))
        d=int(input("Now enter date"))
        nval=datetime.date(datetime(y,m,d))    
    elif col=="id":
        nval=int(input("Enter the value to be set for id"))  
    else:
        nval=input("Enter the value to be set for this column")
    tup=(int(coltbu,nval,col,val)
    print(tup)
    cursor1.execute("Update student set %s=%s where %s=%s"%tup)
    con1.commit()
    con1.close()
```

But this threw a really weird error. It would say

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 489, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Incorrect date value: '1993' for column 'dob' at row 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aliziamojiz/Documents/Alizia/12/prac1.py", line 118, in <module>
    f4()
  File "/Users/aliziamojiz/Documents/Alizia/12/prac1.py", line 113, in f4
    cursor1.execute("Update student set %s=%s where %s=%s"%tup)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 492, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '1993' for column 'dob' at row 4
```

whereas I had not entered 1993 anywhere either in my code or the input I gave.

I am stuck now. How do I take a date as input in a python program and use it in an update command for a mysql table.
Please help out.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would suggest shortening your provided code to just the part where you have trouble with. A minimal working example that's reproducible. This much code is pretty distracting. As for your problem, using the `datetime` module is the best way forward. You could take a look at the `strptime` function as described in the last part of the accepted answer in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200634/program-to-check-if-a-date-is-valid-or-not

Comment: Thanks a lot @CibinJoseph. I did try to reduce the amount of code. Please see if it's any clearer now. I did check out the ```strptime``` function, but I'm not sure why you felt it would solve my problem. From what I understand, it checks the validity of a given/input date.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using datetime to obtain a date seems to be odd. `strptime` will throw a `ValueError` if the format of the date is not as expected or if the date is invalid. It's usually used like so:

```py
dateInput = input("Enter the value to be set for dob in the format yyyy/mm/dd: ")
try:
    dateObject = datetime.strptime(dateInput, "%Y/%m/%d")
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("WRONG DATE FORMAT!")
```

And afterwards, you can use the input date to update your table with `dateObject.date()`.
Additionally, I also suggest you separate the values in the SQL query (to prevent SQL injection) while using `execute` like this:

```
queryValues = (str(dateObject.date()). idInput)
cursor1.execute("UPDATE student SET dob=%s WHERE id=%s", queryValues)
```